# Verificar se a linha selecionada é a penúltima do datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Possuo um dataGridView na tela e preciso que quando o penúltimo registro estiver selecionado, eu mande a seleção pra próxima linha da grid, que no caso seria a ultima.

**Resumo do problema:**

Preciso saber quando a seleção está na penúltima linha da grid, para aplicar um código de ir pra próxima linha, caso essa seleção esteja na penúltima linha.

Parte do código abaixo, a parte de ir pra próxima linha funciona, falta somente a verificação se é a penúltima linha que está selecionada.

```
private void MoveNext()
{
    //Select a proxima linha caso:
    //int last = this.dgvDados.CurrentRow.
    if (//verificação aqui)
    {
        int index = this.dgvDados.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
        index = index % this.dgvDados.Rows.Count;
        this.dgvDados.CurrentCell = this.dgvDados.Rows[index].Cells[this.dgvDados.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dgvDados.CurrentRow.Index` retorna o índice da linha atual.

`dgvDados.Rows.Count` retorna a quantidade de linhas no *grid*. Ou seja, `dgvDados.Rows.Count - 1` é o índice da última linha, logo, `dgvDados.Rows.Count - 2` é o índice da penúltima linha.

Então:

```
if(dgvDados.CurrentRow.Index == dgvDados.Rows.Count - 2)
{
    // A linha selecionada é a penúltima
}
```

Comment: Foi muito mais simples do que imaginei, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado.